# a nonstandard differential equation - product of a function and her consecutive derivatives equal 1

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

For which $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there exists an open interval $I$ and a function $f\colon I\to\mathbb{R}$, that is $n$ times differentiable and $f(x)\cdot f'(x)\cdot\ldots\cdot f^{(n)}(x)=1$ for all $x\in I$?

---

Own problem.

For $n=1$ it's easy to see that $I=(0,\infty)$ and $f(x)=2\sqrt{x}$ work fine.

It seems to complicate a lot already for $n=2$:
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%28x%29*f%27%28x%29*f%27%27%28x%29%3D1 (I hardly understand this reply).

What tools could crack a problem like this?

Comment: If an interval can be a single point, the answer is "all $\mathbb{N}$", because $I = {0}$ and $f_n(x) = e^x$ for all $n$.

Comment: no, no such triviality ;) it's open now

Comment: What about trying $f_n(x) = cx^\alpha$, plugging that to the ODE and solve for $\alpha, c$? Maybe I'm missing something but this strategy seems to work for some values of $n$. E.g. this strategy works for $n=3$ with $f(x) = (-64/27)^{1/4}x^{3/2}$. However, $f$ may output complex values...

Comment: For the $n=2$ case multiply by $f(x)'/f(x)$ and integrate.

Answer (score 3):

Using FeedbackLooper's hint

Assume $f(x) = cx^a$ for some c and some a

We will first find $a$.
$$(cx^a)(cax^{a-1})(ca(a-1)x^{a-2})...(ca(a-1)...(a-n+1)x^{a-n}) = 1x^0$$
Using the fact that the exponents are equal as it holds for all x
$$0 = a + a-1 + a-2 +... +a-n = (n+1)a - \frac{1}{2}n(n+1)$$
$$a=\frac{1}{2}n$$
We can now use the equality of coefficients to find $c$
$$c^{n+1}a^{n}(a-1)^{n-1}...(a-n+1)=1$$
$$c^{n+1}=\frac{1}{a^{n}(a-1)^{n-1}...(a-n+1)}$$
$$c=(a^{n}(a-1)^{n-1}...(a-n+1))^{-\frac{1}{(n+1)}}$$
As we know $a$, we can find $c$ and we have a solution

Note that this only works for odd numbers as the initial product is $0$ for even n and it isn't from $I -> \Bbb{R}$ as it can give complex outputs. This is real if n = 8j + 1 or n = 8j - 1 for integer j. (If you can’t see this, work through the value for c for 5, 7, 9)

I suspect that the complexity for 2 is just the start of the complexity for all even numbers and that nice closed forms don't exist for even numbers

Comment: Thanks. I used the FeedbackLooper's hint and I was already writing a very similar answer, so only to summarize: for $f(x)=cx^a$, the exponent $a=\frac{n}{2}$ makes the product $f(x)\cdot f'(x)\cdot\ldots\cdot f^{(n)}(x)$ constant iff $2\nmid n$ and in this case $c$ should be equal to $\frac{1}{\sqrt[n+1]{\prod_{i=0}^{n}\prod_{j=0}^{i-1}(\frac{n}{2}-j)}}$; it is (and makes a good example) iff the double product below is positive.

Comment: The product is positive whenever $n \equiv \pm1\mod 8$.

Comment: yeah, for $n=7$ we have $c=\sqrt[8]{\frac{268435456}{140710042265625}}=\frac{8}{105}\sqrt[8]{1680}$ giving a good example :)

Comment: I’ve added @eyeballfrog comment to the answer